# How much a one year visa to Vietnam should cost me if I do the visa directly in a Vietnamese consulate?

Tags: tourist-visas, thailand, vietnam

I currently reside in Bangkok, not far from the Vietnamese consulate in this city.

I hold Israeli citizenship which isn't respected for Vietnam E-visa but does allowed one year tourist visa, either directly via a consulate, or indirectly via an [ALBVoA](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153675/how-does-e-visa-differ-from-approval-letter-based-visa-on-arrival-albvoa-for-v) (particularly an ALBVoA which is formally recommended by the Vietnamese embassy of Israel).

I did use an aforementioned ALBVoA twice to make a tourist visa but I think that this time I'd better do it from a consulate directly; firstly due to lower costs (absence of a medium).

### My problem

[it is unclear to me from the chart of the Vietnam embassy in Bangkok](https://vietnamembassy-thailand.org/consular-fees-and-charges/), how much will directly making a one year tourist visa to Vietnam will cost me; I understand from the chart it should cost to me between `135 USD` to `145 USD`, but I am not sure if this understanding is correct.

### My question

How much a one year visa to Vietnam should cost me if I do the visa directly in a Vietnamese consulate?

Comment: Do Vietnam offer 1 year tourist visas? Where did you find this information? I have only ever been able to get 3 months tourist visas.

Comment: @MattDouhan one year tourist visa is something the ALBOVoa recommended by Vietnamese embassy in Israel suggests.

Comment: @MattDouhan https://visaonlinevietnam.com/

Comment: interesting I travel there frequently and I can only get 3 months multiple entries, I am Swedish Citizen,

Comment: @MattDouhan can this be something special to Israelis because Israel saved about 350 Vietnamese refugees in the days of the war and today there are about 1,000 Israeli Vietnamese?

Comment: maybe this is the case

Comment: @MattDouhan hello ; I called the Bangkokian Vietnamese embassy today --- I understood that only U.S.A citizens get more than 3 months visa to Vietnam. It's I heard this by phone instead going to the embassy with the intention of making a one year visa or much worse --- paying some ALBVoA about 360 USD and perhaps getting very depressed at Tan Son Nhat.